(Where am I making a mistake?) finding expression for t in terms of h and H of cone given dV/dt
A tank containing water is in the form of a cone with vertex C. The axis is vertical and the semi-vertical angle is $60^o$. AT t=0, the tank is full and the depth of water is H. At this instant a tap at C is opened and water begins to flow out. The volume of water in the tank decreases at a rate proportional to $\sqrt h$ where h is the depth o fwater at time t. The tank becomes empty when t=60.
So from this I understood
r= $\sqrt 3$ h
V= $\frac 13 \pi r^2h=\pi h^3 $
$\frac {dV}{dt}= -k\sqrt h$
and $\frac {dV}{dt}= 3 \pi h^2 \frac {dh}{dt}$
so $\frac {dh}{dt}= \frac {-k}{3\pi h^{1.5}}$ and $\frac{dt}{dh}$ is the reciprocal
They want me to solve the above differential equation to obtain an expression for t in terms of h and H.
I solved it (using integration) and got $\frac {-kt}{3\pi}= \frac 25h^{\frac 52}+c$
;  $\frac {-kt}{3\pi}= \frac 25h^{\frac 52}- \frac25H^\frac 52$
$k= \frac {\pi}{50}H^\frac52$ --> $\frac{-\pi}{50}H^\frac52t +\frac25H^\frac52=\frac25h^\frac52$
But this was incorrect and the answer was actually $\frac{1}{150}H^\frac52t +\frac25H^\frac52=\frac25h^\frac52$
Where did I go wrong with my solution?

You forgot to divide k = π/50 * H^(5/2) by 3π after inserting it in the solution of the differential equation for h.

Thank you
